# IIS 7 - IP Address Range Restriction

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to setup an IP address range. It's asking for:

A) IP Address Range  (but it will only accept a normal IP address)

B) Mask or Prefix

I need to allow 192.168.100.100 - 192.168.100.120

How can I make that happen?

[image]

Comment: I have the same question, but I don't see a good answer. So how would I be able to block for example the range: 4.4.4.0? What subnet mask do I need to provide?

Comment: I suppose that using the IP Subnet Calculator linked in Vivek's answer will get you to an answer. I think an IP address of 4.4.4.0 with subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 will do the trick - assuming that you want to reject traffic from 4.4.4.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the IP Address and a proper subnet mask. I just used [IP Subnet Calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/) to calculate the subnet mask for the address 192.168.100.100. So if you specify  the subnet 255.255.255.240 for 14 nodes.

Comment: Which incidentally would not solve his problem - alone. He needs 100 to 120 ;) 20 nodes.

Comment: just play around with the subnet mask.. thats it :)

Answer (score 2):

By entering a lot of individual addresses.

100-120 is not doable in a single masked entry. It just does not align properly with any mask possible.

Be also carefull whether what you do makes any sense. Users with enough rights can change their ip address - so, this is only barefuly usable in limited scenarios within a LAN. I would suggest not filtering by IP address, but using user identities / accounts if possible.